# How to interpret autocorrelation plot for differencing?

Tags: time-series, python, interpretation, autocorrelation, lags

I'm trying to assess and remove seasonality from yearly climate data. I don't have a stats background, just fyi. My understanding is that I can use an autocorrelation plot to determine the proper lag to use with the differencing method of removing seasonality. Is this true? And how do you interpret the autocorrelation plots to determine the lag to use with differencing? Bellow are some example outputs of the raw data (with lowess in red and difference between actual and lowess in green) and the autocorrelation plots.

Also, on all of my plots (I've got 8 different points/locations, 4 different GCMs (global climate models) and 8 different climate variables) the confidence intervals seem fixed.. but this should be dependent on the data... and I can't find any python documentation (I'm using the autocorrelation_plot() for Pandas in Python). Is the command normalizing the data in some way? Thank you in advance.
[image: April 1st snowpack from the Basin Characterization Model output for GCM GFDL A2 from 1900 - 2099 for a point located in northern California]

[image: Autocorrelation plot for April 1st snowpack from the Basin Characterization Model output for GCM GFDL A2 from 1900 - 2099 for a point located in northern California]

[image: Autocorrelation plot for April 1st snowpack from the Basin Characterization Model output for GCM GFDL A2 from 1900 - 2099 for a point located in northern California]

Comment: If you have *yearly* data, you can't detect seasonality, unless you posit multi-year cycles (e.g., driven by sunspots). For understanding the role of ACF/PACF plots, you may want to look at the free online
[*Forecasting: Principles and Practice* by
Hyndman & Athanasopoulos](https://otexts.org/fpp2/) textbook, even if you do not plan on forecasting per se.

Comment: Ahh I suppose I mean "cycles" then instead of "seasons." I do also have monthly data... but ultimately I'm interested in trying to meet assumptions for the Mann-Kendall trend test; I want to know if there is a trend in the yearly data. But since the variance isn't constant, I'm looking to remove any seasonality/cyclic patterns from the data to meet the assumptions so I can run the trend test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A tentative answer from a non-expert in time series analysis]

You have departed from the usual and I believe the correct order of steps in this sort of analysis.  First one examines the raw time series to determine whether there is a secular trend, i.e., whether the mean value of the series is systematically changing as a function of time.  If it is, you difference the series once (subtract each value from the following value, or for seasonality from a value a certain number of lags ahead).  Then you examine the resulting series to see whether a secular trend remains (which would prompt additional differencing) or whether you can proceed to the next step.  That next step is to examine the autocorrelations and partial autocorrelations of the differenced series (if applicable) to see whether you have white noise or whether it makes sense to fit a model to the series.

Confidence intervals are a function of the sample size, which is static here.

Comment: thank you much for your reply. So in the first figure the blue is the raw data which has a changing mean over time (red lines), which means I should difference the data, but how do I determine the seasonal lag? By eyeballing? Looks like about 50-60 years, is this correct? It was my understanding that using the autocorrelation plot I could better determine the lag for differencing...? or is this not true?

Comment: For the seasonal lag, examine autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation plots in order to find regularly spaced peaks (whose height may decrease) and the corresponding "period" gives you the number of lags you should use if you need to perform seasonal differencing.